# How to set custom title when merging two different OpenAPI files using openapi-merge-cli?

Tags: openapi

I have two different OAS files, oam1.yaml & oam2.yaml.
Now, I want to merge them. To merge I am using `npx openapi-merge-cli` which does the job and I am getting the merged file.

The `npx openapi-merge-cli` tool uses something called `openapi-merge.json` configuration file where we are going to specify which two files we want to combine, what will be the merged file, etc.
But the issue is that the merged output OAS file takes the first OAS file's title as the title.

From the [documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/openapi-merge-cli), I can see that there are some parameters that we can use to specify the title of final merged file:

```
 description.title: An optional field, that lets you spefify a custom heading for this inputs
 description when it is merged together in the output OpenAPI file.
```

I need help how to use this `description.title` in my JSON file.
My `openapi-merge.json` file looks like this:

```json
{
  "inputs": [
    {
      "inputFile": "./oam1.yaml"
    },
    {
      "inputFile": "./oam2.yaml"
    }
  ],
  "output": "./merged-api.yaml"
}
```